# Can we use table objects as positional parameters in jdbc?

Tags: jdbc

Main Query:

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM employee WHERE eno = 1");
```

Working: by concatenation

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM "+tn+" WHERE "+cn+" = ?");
```

Not Working: when used positional parameter

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM ? WHERE ? = ?");
```

Can we use positional parameters only for working with table data?

Why I'm not able to work with table_name, column_name etc.?

Comment: No that's not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point of a prepared statement is to let the database prepare an execution plan (i.e. compute what needs to be done, using which tables, indices, joining strategies, algorithms, etc.), and then to execute that plan one or several times with various parameters.

If the database doesn't even know which table it must delete from, based on which criteria, there's no way it can prepare the execution plan.